# Inherited elements C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

i have two c++ classes, one which inherits an abstract base class for a student database.
The base class is the record which contains all the student information (name, id vector of courses & marks):

```
class student{
protected:
    string fName,sName;
    int id;
    vector<string> cname;
    vector<double> cmark;
public:
    virtual ~student();
    virtual void addClass(string name, double mark)=0;
};
```

I Need to be able to access the vector cname and cmark in the `addCourse` function in the below class

```
class degree : public student{
public:
    degree(string f, string s, int i){
        this->setName(f,s); 
        this->setID(i);
    }
    ~degree();

    void AddCourse(string name, int mark){

    }
```

I dont know how to do this without making a `set` function in the base class like i have done with the `degree` constructor.

I could just make a set function in the base class but i would rather some method of initializing the inherited elements without using functions, just to make the code less messy, is this possible? i thought about using `this->cname` but that gave me errors.

Comment: What error did you get from using `this->cname`?

Comment: You have access to both vectors in ``AddCourse``.

Comment: If degree inherits from student, you are essentially asserting that a degree is a student. Which doesn't sound right.

Comment: I agree completely, but the project description says it has to be done like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I Need to be able to access the vector cname and cmark in the addCourse function in the below class

Just access them, they are protected, so derived classes have access:

```
void AddCourse(string name, int mark){
  cname.push_back(name);
  cmark.push_back(mark);
}
```